# muteHttpExceptions jump to line 86 if error in UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, urlfetch

I wish that when there was an error, the script would continue from line 86. But when I try to save the script, it says that there is a failure because ";" before the declaration. What am I forgetting?

```
function onOpen( ){
  // This line calls the SpreadsheetApp and gets its UI   
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  //These lines create the menu items and 
  // tie them to functions we will write in Apps Script

  ui.createMenu('Atualizar Clima')
  .addItem('Ativar', 'TudoCompleto')
  .addToUi();
}

function TudoCompleto() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  //Clima
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTXML(\'Clima\'!F20,"//*[@id=\'page_team_1_block_venue_info_3\']/div/div[1]/dl/dt")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!F21:F45').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1:A25').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  //Clima 2
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setFormula('=IMPORTXML(\'Clima\'!F20,"//*[@id=\'page_team_1_block_venue_info_3\']/div/div[1]/dl/dd")');
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!G21:G44').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1:A24').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

  //CLIMA  
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!A3:B8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Clima");
  var apiKey = "c9e1e7816ecc0e8eaeda584109d342bf"; // Or you can try my key

  var cityName = sheet.getRange("A1").getValue();
  // Go to https://openweathermap.org, register and get a free API key
  var apiCall = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + cityName +"&appid=" + apiKey;

  options = { 'muteHttpExceptions' : true};
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiCall, options);
  if (response.cod != "404") {
    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

    var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // planilha ativa
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Clima"); 

    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

      var cel = "H"+ i //

      if (sheet.getRange(cel).getValue() != "")  {   

        for (var u = 1; i < 1000; u++) {
          var cel2 = "M"+ u //

          if (sheet.getRange(cel2).getValue() == "")  { 

            sheet.getRange("M"+u).setValue(sheet.getRange(cel).getValue());
            break;
          };
        }
      }
    };
    spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
    spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!F16').activate();
    spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  }

  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());

  var weather = data["weather"][0]; //It's an array
  var sys = data["sys"];
  var main = data["main"]
  var location = data["name"];
  var country = sys["country"];
  var weatherDesc = weather["main"];
  var temp = main["temp"];
  var minTemp = main["temp_min"];
  var maxTemp = main["temp_max"];

  var weatherData = [
    ["Location:", location],
    ["Country:", country],
    ["Weather:", weatherDesc],
    ["Teaperture:", temp],
    ["Min Temp:", minTemp],
    ["Max Temp:", maxTemp]
  ];

  sheet.getRange(3, 1, weatherData.length, weatherData[0].length).setValues(weatherData);



  //The API Call works
  // The Data will be retrieved like below JSON file.
  //{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
  //"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
  //"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],
  //"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
  //"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
  //"rain":{"3h":0},
  //"clouds":{"all":92},
  //"dt":1369824698,
  //"id":1851632,
  //"name":"Shuzenji",
  //"cod":200}

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // planilha ativa
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Clima"); 

  for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

    var cel = "H"+ i //

    if (sheet.getRange(cel).getValue() != "")  {   

      for (var u = 1; i < 1000; u++) {
        var cel2 = "M"+ u //

        if (sheet.getRange(cel2).getValue() == "")  { 

          sheet.getRange("M"+u).setValue(sheet.getRange(cel).getValue());
          break;
        };
      }
    }
  };
  spreadsheet.getRange('Monster!A1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('Clima!F16').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
}
```

When I execute it, it does all the actions, but eventually an error message appears, saying:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

Basically, this is not how JavaScript (and Google Apps Script, which is based on it) works. There are no `goto` statements in JS and therefore no line jumping (label statements being the exception, but their usage is limited).

**Solution**

You'll need to make logic implemented on line 86 a separate `function` for it to be reused and call it inside your `if` statement or reuse the code on line 86 with new parameters.

**Modification points**

1. `response!=404` in your case is always `true` as `HTTPResponse` class instance will never be equal to an integer. Take a look at the reference below, to get response code you'll need to call a `getResponseCode()` method.
2. Besides, if you are checking *for an error to occur*, you should use equality comparison `==` instead of inequality `!=`.

**Reference**

1. Label statements [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) on MDN;
2. `HTTPResponse` class [reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response);

Comment: Oleg Valter, I edited the question and published the whole script with some adjustments in IF, but now a new error has appeared while trying to execute ... The error is below the code, could you help me please? Thank you

Comment: Frederico, first, you should really take a look at the `HTTPResponse` documentation - `response.code != "404"` won't help due to the same reason I described. The issue here is that `response` is a variable to which an `HTTPResponse` class instance is written. And the only way you are getting status code from it is via `getResponseCode()`... As for the error you are getting - when you use `getContentText()` you get a `String` back -> there is no `weather` property. If API returns a JSON response, parse it before doing anything - `JSON.parse(yourRefHere)` will do just fine

Comment: Though, upon further examination, your `data` might not have a `weather` property at all (please, disregard the second part of my previous comment as I missed that you actually parse the response content)